# How to count total amount of pending tickets monday in oracle-sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I want to count the total amount of pending tickets for monday. I don't want the amount of tickets that were moved to pending on monday but the total amount.
table with sample data:
[image]

Expected result:
Total pending tickets monday

Comment: How do you know if a ticket is pending?  How is a ticket defined?  And what is "monday"?  There is no indication of what that refers to in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each row represents a ticket, then you can get the number that are pending on a particular day using:

```
select count(*)
from t
where updated_at < :date and status = 'pending';
```

Note:  This is not going to count "pending" statuses that were changed to another state.  This data does not have enough information to answer that.  And your question has not explained the state changes.

I would actually suggest that you ask a *new* question with more comprehensive information about what the states are, how they change as well as sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the tickets which are not closed are pending. You can use the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS PENDING FROM YOUR_TABLE T
 WHERE T.CREATED_AT <= <<YOUR_DATE>>
 GROUP BY T.TICKET_ID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN T.STATUS = 'closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```